# Lebesgue Integral Over Step Function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, riemann-integration, measurable-functions

Given the step function

\begin{equation}
  g(x,y) =
    \begin{cases}
      \frac{1}{x^2} & 0<y<x<1\\
      -\frac{1}{y^2} & 0<x<y<1\\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}

I want to show that

$$\int_{(0,1)}\int_{(0,1)} g(x,y) \, d\lambda(x)\,d\lambda(y) \neq \int_{(0,1)}\int_{(0,1)} g(x,y) \,d\lambda(y)\,d\lambda(x)$$

However, when trying to use the relation with Riemann integrability I end up with divergent integrals such as

$$\int_0^x \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2} \, dx \, dy - \int_0^1 \int_0^y \frac{1}{y^2} \, dx \, dy$$

I also considered using limits such as following one, but again I end up with divergence.
$$\lim_{k \rightarrow\infty} \int_{(\frac{1}{k},1)}\lim_{k \rightarrow\infty} \int_{(\frac{1}{k},1)}g(x,y) \, dx \, dy$$

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: The notation $$\int_0^x \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2} \, dx \, dy$$ makes no sense. Look more closely.

Comment: @MichaelHardy you are right, I didn't notice it was $\int_0^x \int_y^1$, same with the other term!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \int_{(0,1)} \left( \int_{(0,1)} g(x,y) \, d\lambda(x) \right) \,d\lambda(y) \\[8pt]
= {} & \int_{(0,1)} \left( \int_{(0,y)} -\frac 1 {y^2} \, d\lambda(x) + \int_{(y,1)} \frac 1 {x^2} \,d\lambda(x) \right) \, d\lambda(y) \\[8pt]
= {} & \int_{(0,1)} \left( -\frac 1 y + \frac{1-y} y \right) \, d\lambda(y) =\int_{(0,1)} -1\, d\lambda(y) = -1.
\end{align}